# Actionscript splitter panel for desktop applications

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there a method to implement a splitter panel for desktop applications?

I'm searching for something similar to the SplitViewNavigator for mobile apps.

Is there a library or I have to write it myself?

Here is a [picture](http://wijmo.com/widgets/wijmo-open/splitter/) of what I mean for splitter panel:

[image: Splitter example]

Comment: How about HDividedBox and VDividedBox ?http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e54.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days of research I find a method to implement the vertical splitter panel without relying on mobile components: I use a thin (4 pixels) button between the panels, then while drag and dropping this button, I change the width of the left panel according to mouse horizontal position.

Some sample code:

```
<s:HGroup>
    <s:Panel id="panel1" width="50%" height="100%"/>
    <s:Button width="4" height="100%" 
              mouseOver="mousePointerDrag()" 
              mouseOut ="mousePointerDrop()" 
              mouseDown="mouseDownHResize()"
              mouseUp  ="mouseUpHResize()"/>
    <s:Panel id="panel2" width="50%" height="100%"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

The mouseOver and mouseOut change the pointer into a hand while over the split button:

```
private function mousePointerDrag():void
{
    Mouse.cursor = "hand";
}
private function mousePointerDrop():void
{
    Mouse.cursor = "auto";
}
```

the mouseDown and mouseUp enable a resize event listener to resize the panel1 width (panel2 will change accordingly):

```
private function mouseDownHResize():void
{
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHResize);
}
private function mouseUpHResize():void
{
    this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHResize);
}
private function mouseMoveHResize(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    panel1.width = event.stageX-4-4; // tricky part
}
```

The tricky part is to select the correct width of the panel1, in order to make sure the mouse pointer remains in the resize button when the mouse is released (in this case 4 pixels for the border.

Of course for horizontal splitter is something similiar.

I am new in ActionScript programming so this could be a bad solution, but it was the simpler I found so far; if other cleaner solutions are available they can be added to this question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Flex Mobile components for desktop Applications. I found this [tutorial](http://devgirl.org/2011/10/19/using-flex-mobile-components-in-a-flexair-desktop-application/) you could follow